# Finishing activities in android

Tags: android, android-activity, instance

well i have a strange problem .. when user exits the app by pressing button i have used a code that finishes all activities only one time .. but if that activity is created more than one time then it finishes it only once .. can i check how many times an activity is created and destroy them so that on pressing back button user dont find any activity alive 
code is here

```
if(ActivityA.instanceA != null) {
    try {  
        Activity.instanceA.finish(); 
    } catch (Exception e) {}
}
```

Comment: why this problem happens, are you using  fragments ??

Comment: Why finish an activity?

Comment: no i am not using fragments

Comment: In general you don't explicitly finish activities unless you are specifically needing to perform an action in the onDestroy event for final cleanup. Alternately you could finish an activity if you were needing to return a result from it. Ideally the platform will dispose of the activity itself.

Comment: actually i have provided logout fuctionality.. when user clicks logout button, it takes him to login screen.. but when he pressess back button he gets all activities alive.. that is not ok .. so i have to do something like this #sreekanth

Comment: #Matt kindly check my above comment and guide me please

Comment: Ah, so essentially you want to remove the backstack when you return to the login screen. Assuming you are using an intent you can use the intent flags FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK. Digvesh's answer would then be correct. If you could please edit the original question to provide the extra detail about the logout and returning to the initial activity. It will help discoverability later.

Comment: ok thanks but i am not geeting what is "anim" in his code?

Comment: @SparrOw When you come back from your previous activity to current activity at that time your previous activity will be destroyed. If you want to close all activities you need to set flags for activity.

Comment: @Piyush but how it will happen?

Comment: In your every activity onDestroy() method called automatically when you back from that activity.

Comment: @piyush i am not pressing back button on every activity .. when user will press logout button it takes him to login screen again .. but when i press back button from login screen all activities that were previously used were alive

Comment: @SparrOw Just check my answer. And yes you want to close all activities there is another way to maintain Stack for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add flags for Intent when you call new Activity.

```
 intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

The above line indicates that all activities on top of the YourCurrentActivity are cleared.

You can add this property for your every activity in your Manifest file.

```
android:noHistory="true"
android:clearTaskOnLaunch="true"
```

Comment: i did this .. but its not helping me :(

Comment: @SparrOw In every activity which was created??

Comment: @SparrOw Then you need to do for all activity. And also check my edited answer.

Comment: cool .. ok u mean to say i have to do this for every activity and for every intent that is going to start a new activity in my application?

Comment: @SparrOw Yes now you understand what my mean to say to you.

Comment: oh .. thank you so much .. i am going to try this and i will let u know if any problem accurs .. ok?

Comment: @SparrOw Ya okay if you have any problem you can reach to me after showing my profile.

Answer (score 0):

```
Intent i = new Intent(AboutApp_Activity.this,
                        Home_Activity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                        | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

                startActivity(i);
                finish();
                overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right,
                        R.anim.slide_out_right);
```

Comment: #Digvesh ! what is "anim"?

Comment: just ignore that hole line

Comment: i ignored that line but when i pressed back button .. all activities were alive ..

Comment: i am not experienced enough .. its my first application .. can u plz tell me how to add this line in menifest